# How to set withCredentials=true in HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient, blazor-webassembly

I want to set `withCredentials=true` in a C# `HttpClient` request - how to do this?

```
var res = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44387/api/values/SetCookie");
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71000358/941240) looks like your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `HttpClientHandler` class and setting its `UseDefaultCredentials` property to `true`.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    // Optionally, you can also set other properties of HttpClientHandler here
};

var client = new HttpClient(handler);
var res = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44387/api/values/SetCookie");
```

Comment: `handler` and `client` need `using` to dispose, or make them `static`