# Blazor WASM: unable to retrieve cookies

Tags: javascript, c#, cookies, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

I have a cookie that exists in F12/Application/Sorage/Cookies, however, I am unable to retrieve it.

Blazor:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var token = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getCookie");
    Console.WriteLine($"token {token}");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
    {
        posts = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Post>>("api/post/list");
        Console.WriteLine("List Refreshed");
    }
    else
    {
        NavigationManager?.NavigateTo("/loginx");
    }
}
```

var token is null and I don't know why that's the case..

JS:

```
    window.getCookie = function () {
    return document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)authToken\s*=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
};
```

Cookie-creation at one of my API endpoints

```
DateTime expirationTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1); 
Response.Cookies.Append("authToken", token, new CookieOptions
{
    HttpOnly = true,
    Secure = true, 
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
    Expires = expirationTime, 
    Domain = "localhost", 
    Path = "/", 
               
});
```

Comment: Try decode cookie with decodeURIComponent(document.cookie) follow this issue:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63831943/httpclient-doesnt-include-cookies-with-requests-in-blazor-webassembly-app

Comment: @RuikaiFeng It is not related to that issue; my cookie is httpOnly, JS can't reach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally missed it. The Cookie that is put in use is HttpOnly which means it is not accessible by JS; therefore, I found some other way to check the authentication status.

Here is the approach I used:

Api

```
[HttpGet("checkAuthStatus")]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult CheckAuthStatus()
{
    return Ok(new { IsLoggedIn = true });
}
```

Blazor

```
private bool isLoggedIn;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var authStatusResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync("api/Auth2/checkAuthStatus");

    if (authStatusResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        isLoggedIn = true;
        await RefreshPosts();
    }
    else
    {
        NavigationManager?.NavigateTo("/loginx");
    }
}
```