# Why doesn't my Web API set any cookies in browser, even though they are in repsonse from the API?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, blazor, webapi, setcookie

I have Web API built on ASP.Net Core, using JWT Authentication. My current problem is that I had an unsafe way of sendnig to and savind on the client Refresh Token. Now I'm gtrying to make My API to send it via Http-Only Cookie and it does. The API sends it in login response, but it isn't saved in browser's cookie storage. Currently I implemented "safe sending" only in Login endpoint, in User's Controller.
Here's projects repository: https://github.com/Nauaho/apbd-pro

Update 1, Here's the code:

```
     public async Task<TokenSet?> LoginUser(string username, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                Email = (string?)null,
                Login = username,
                Password = password
            });
            using HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            using StringContent content = new(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            using var response = await client.PostAsync(_apiLink + "/api/users/login", content);
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return null;
            var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            if (value is null)
                return null;
            Login = username;
            AccessToken = value.AccessToken;
            var cookies = GetCookies(response);
            cookies.ToList().ForEach(cookie => Console.WriteLine(cookie.Name + " : " + cookie.Value));
            Console.WriteLine("accessToken : " + value.AccessToken);
            return new TokenSet {AccessToken = AccessToken, RefreshToken = RefreshToken };
        }
```

P.S. Method GetCookies Returns cookies(IEnumerable of CookieState objects) that were in received response, and yes: refresh tokens is amongst them too.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please don't point to an external source for your code but include it (only the required portions) in the question (formatted as code)

Comment: From your code, It seems you can't set/get cookie in your blazor, Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54024644/how-do-i-create-a-cookie-client-side-using-blazor).

Comment: @XinranShen, thanks for the answer. I know how to save cookies using JSInterpop< but unfortunately I can't use it, since the cookies must be HttpOnly. Thanks again for a comment

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, I edited my question as you recommended, or at least I tried, thanks for a comment